# Memory coalescing and nvprof results on NVIDIA Pascal

Tags: cuda, gpu, nvidia, memory-access, coalescing

I am running a memory coalescing experiment on Pascal and getting unexpected `nvprof` results. I have one kernel that copies 4 GB of floats from one array to another one. `nvprof` reports confusing numbers for `gld_transactions_per_request` and `gst_transactions_per_request`.

I ran the experiment on a TITAN Xp and a GeForce GTX 1080 TI. Same results.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdint>
#include <assert.h>

#define N 1ULL*1024*1024*1024

#define gpuErrchk(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }
inline void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, const char *file, int line, bool abort=true)
{
   if (code != cudaSuccess) 
   {
      fprintf(stderr,"GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
      if (abort) exit(code);
   }
}


__global__ void copy_kernel(
      const float* __restrict__ data, float* __restrict__ data2) {
  for (unsigned int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
       tid < N; tid += blockDim.x * gridDim.x) {
    data2[tid] = data[tid];
  }
}

int main() {
  float* d_data;
  gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_data, sizeof(float) * N));
  assert(d_data != nullptr);
  uintptr_t d = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(d_data);
  assert(d%128 == 0);  // check alignment, just to be sure

  float* d_data2;
  gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_data2, sizeof(float)*N));
  assert(d_data2 != nullptr);

  copy_kernel<<<1024,1024>>>(d_data, d_data2);
  gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
}
```

Compiled with CUDA version 10.1:

```
nvcc coalescing.cu -std=c++11 -Xptxas -dlcm=ca -gencode arch=compute_61,code=sm_61 -O3
```

Profiled with:

```
nvprof -m all ./a.out
```

There are a few confusing parts in the profiling results:

- `gld_transactions = 536870914`, which means that every global load transaction should on average be `4GB/536870914 = 8 bytes`. This is consistent with `gld_transactions_per_request = 16.000000`: Each warp reads 128 bytes (1 request) and if every transaction is 8 bytes, then we need `128 / 8 = 16` transactions per request. Why is this value so low? I would expect perfect coalescing, so something along the lines of 4 (or even 1) transactions/request.
- `gst_transactions = 134217728` and `gst_transactions_per_request = 4.000000`, so storing memory is more efficient?
- Requested and achieved global load/store throughput (`gld_requested_throughput`, `gst_requested_throughput`, `gld_throughput`, `gst_throughput`) is `150.32GB/s` each. I would expect a lower throughput for loads than for stores since we have more transactions per request.
- `gld_transactions = 536870914` but `l2_read_transactions = 134218800`. Global memory is always accessed through the L1/L2 caches. Why is the number of L2 read transactions so much lower? It can't all be cached in the L1. (`global_hit_rate = 0%`)

I think I am reading the `nvprof` results wrong. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Here is the full profiling result:

```
Device "GeForce GTX 1080 Ti (0)"
    Kernel: copy_kernel(float const *, float*)
          1                             inst_per_warp                                                 Instructions per warp  1.4346e+04  1.4346e+04  1.4346e+04
          1                         branch_efficiency                                                     Branch Efficiency     100.00%     100.00%     100.00%
          1                 warp_execution_efficiency                                             Warp Execution Efficiency     100.00%     100.00%     100.00%
          1         warp_nonpred_execution_efficiency                              Warp Non-Predicated Execution Efficiency      99.99%      99.99%      99.99%
          1                      inst_replay_overhead                                           Instruction Replay Overhead    0.000178    0.000178    0.000178
          1      shared_load_transactions_per_request                           Shared Memory Load Transactions Per Request    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
          1     shared_store_transactions_per_request                          Shared Memory Store Transactions Per Request    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
          1       local_load_transactions_per_request                            Local Memory Load Transactions Per Request    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
          1      local_store_transactions_per_request                           Local Memory Store Transactions Per Request    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
          1              gld_transactions_per_request                                  Global Load Transactions Per Request   16.000000   16.000000   16.000000
          1              gst_transactions_per_request                                 Global Store Transactions Per Request    4.000000    4.000000    4.000000
          1                 shared_store_transactions                                             Shared Store Transactions           0           0           0
          1                  shared_load_transactions                                              Shared Load Transactions           0           0           0
          1                   local_load_transactions                                               Local Load Transactions           0           0           0
          1                  local_store_transactions                                              Local Store Transactions           0           0           0
          1                          gld_transactions                                              Global Load Transactions   536870914   536870914   536870914
          1                          gst_transactions                                             Global Store Transactions   134217728   134217728   134217728
          1                  sysmem_read_transactions                                       System Memory Read Transactions           0           0           0
          1                 sysmem_write_transactions                                      System Memory Write Transactions           5           5           5
          1                      l2_read_transactions                                                  L2 Read Transactions   134218800   134218800   134218800
          1                     l2_write_transactions                                                 L2 Write Transactions   134217741   134217741   134217741
          1                           global_hit_rate                                     Global Hit Rate in unified l1/tex       0.00%       0.00%       0.00%
          1                            local_hit_rate                                                        Local Hit Rate       0.00%       0.00%       0.00%
          1                  gld_requested_throughput                                      Requested Global Load Throughput  150.32GB/s  150.32GB/s  150.32GB/s
          1                  gst_requested_throughput                                     Requested Global Store Throughput  150.32GB/s  150.32GB/s  150.32GB/s
          1                            gld_throughput                                                Global Load Throughput  150.32GB/s  150.32GB/s  150.32GB/s
          1                            gst_throughput                                               Global Store Throughput  150.32GB/s  150.32GB/s  150.32GB/s
          1                     local_memory_overhead                                                 Local Memory Overhead       0.00%       0.00%       0.00%
          1                        tex_cache_hit_rate                                                Unified Cache Hit Rate      50.00%      50.00%      50.00%
          1                      l2_tex_read_hit_rate                                           L2 Hit Rate (Texture Reads)       0.00%       0.00%       0.00%
          1                     l2_tex_write_hit_rate                                          L2 Hit Rate (Texture Writes)       0.00%       0.00%       0.00%
          1                      tex_cache_throughput                                              Unified Cache Throughput  150.32GB/s  150.32GB/s  150.32GB/s
          1                    l2_tex_read_throughput                                         L2 Throughput (Texture Reads)  150.32GB/s  150.32GB/s  150.32GB/s
          1                   l2_tex_write_throughput                                        L2 Throughput (Texture Writes)  150.32GB/s  150.32GB/s  150.32GB/s
          1                        l2_read_throughput                                                 L2 Throughput (Reads)  150.32GB/s  150.32GB/s  150.32GB/s
          1                       l2_write_throughput                                                L2 Throughput (Writes)  150.32GB/s  150.32GB/s  150.32GB/s
          1                    sysmem_read_throughput                                         System Memory Read Throughput  0.00000B/s  0.00000B/s  0.00000B/s
          1                   sysmem_write_throughput                                        System Memory Write Throughput  5.8711KB/s  5.8711KB/s  5.8701KB/s
          1                     local_load_throughput                                          Local Memory Load Throughput  0.00000B/s  0.00000B/s  0.00000B/s
          1                    local_store_throughput                                         Local Memory Store Throughput  0.00000B/s  0.00000B/s  0.00000B/s
          1                    shared_load_throughput                                         Shared Memory Load Throughput  0.00000B/s  0.00000B/s  0.00000B/s
          1                   shared_store_throughput                                        Shared Memory Store Throughput  0.00000B/s  0.00000B/s  0.00000B/s
          1                            gld_efficiency                                         Global Memory Load Efficiency     100.00%     100.00%     100.00%
          1                            gst_efficiency                                        Global Memory Store Efficiency     100.00%     100.00%     100.00%
          1                    tex_cache_transactions                                            Unified Cache Transactions   134217728   134217728   134217728
          1                             flop_count_dp                           Floating Point Operations(Double Precision)           0           0           0
          1                         flop_count_dp_add                       Floating Point Operations(Double Precision Add)           0           0           0
          1                         flop_count_dp_fma                       Floating Point Operations(Double Precision FMA)           0           0           0
          1                         flop_count_dp_mul                       Floating Point Operations(Double Precision Mul)           0           0           0
          1                             flop_count_sp                           Floating Point Operations(Single Precision)           0           0           0
          1                         flop_count_sp_add                       Floating Point Operations(Single Precision Add)           0           0           0
          1                         flop_count_sp_fma                       Floating Point Operations(Single Precision FMA)           0           0           0
          1                         flop_count_sp_mul                        Floating Point Operation(Single Precision Mul)           0           0           0
          1                     flop_count_sp_special                   Floating Point Operations(Single Precision Special)           0           0           0
          1                             inst_executed                                                 Instructions Executed   470089728   470089728   470089728
          1                               inst_issued                                                   Instructions Issued   470173430   470173430   470173430
          1                        sysmem_utilization                                             System Memory Utilization     Low (1)     Low (1)     Low (1)
          1                          stall_inst_fetch                              Issue Stall Reasons (Instructions Fetch)       0.79%       0.79%       0.79%
          1                     stall_exec_dependency                            Issue Stall Reasons (Execution Dependency)       1.46%       1.46%       1.46%
          1                   stall_memory_dependency                                    Issue Stall Reasons (Data Request)      96.16%      96.16%      96.16%
          1                             stall_texture                                         Issue Stall Reasons (Texture)       0.00%       0.00%       0.00%
          1                                stall_sync                                 Issue Stall Reasons (Synchronization)       0.00%       0.00%       0.00%
          1                               stall_other                                           Issue Stall Reasons (Other)       1.13%       1.13%       1.13%
          1          stall_constant_memory_dependency                              Issue Stall Reasons (Immediate constant)       0.00%       0.00%       0.00%
          1                           stall_pipe_busy                                       Issue Stall Reasons (Pipe Busy)       0.07%       0.07%       0.07%
          1                         shared_efficiency                                              Shared Memory Efficiency       0.00%       0.00%       0.00%
          1                                inst_fp_32                                               FP Instructions(Single)           0           0           0
          1                                inst_fp_64                                               FP Instructions(Double)           0           0           0
          1                              inst_integer                                                  Integer Instructions  1.0742e+10  1.0742e+10  1.0742e+10
          1                          inst_bit_convert                                              Bit-Convert Instructions           0           0           0
          1                              inst_control                                             Control-Flow Instructions  1073741824  1073741824  1073741824
          1                        inst_compute_ld_st                                               Load/Store Instructions  2147483648  2147483648  2147483648
          1                                 inst_misc                                                     Misc Instructions  1077936128  1077936128  1077936128
          1           inst_inter_thread_communication                                             Inter-Thread Instructions           0           0           0
          1                               issue_slots                                                           Issue Slots   470173430   470173430   470173430
          1                                 cf_issued                                      Issued Control-Flow Instructions    33619968    33619968    33619968
          1                               cf_executed                                    Executed Control-Flow Instructions    33619968    33619968    33619968
          1                               ldst_issued                                        Issued Load/Store Instructions   268500992   268500992   268500992
          1                             ldst_executed                                      Executed Load/Store Instructions    67174400    67174400    67174400
          1                       atomic_transactions                                                   Atomic Transactions           0           0           0
          1           atomic_transactions_per_request                                       Atomic Transactions Per Request    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
          1                      l2_atomic_throughput                                       L2 Throughput (Atomic requests)  0.00000B/s  0.00000B/s  0.00000B/s
          1                    l2_atomic_transactions                                     L2 Transactions (Atomic requests)           0           0           0
          1                  l2_tex_read_transactions                                       L2 Transactions (Texture Reads)   134217728   134217728   134217728
          1                     stall_memory_throttle                                 Issue Stall Reasons (Memory Throttle)       0.00%       0.00%       0.00%
          1                        stall_not_selected                                    Issue Stall Reasons (Not Selected)       0.39%       0.39%       0.39%
          1                 l2_tex_write_transactions                                      L2 Transactions (Texture Writes)   134217728   134217728   134217728
          1                             flop_count_hp                             Floating Point Operations(Half Precision)           0           0           0
          1                         flop_count_hp_add                         Floating Point Operations(Half Precision Add)           0           0           0
          1                         flop_count_hp_mul                          Floating Point Operation(Half Precision Mul)           0           0           0
          1                         flop_count_hp_fma                         Floating Point Operations(Half Precision FMA)           0           0           0
          1                                inst_fp_16                                                 HP Instructions(Half)           0           0           0
          1                   sysmem_read_utilization                                        System Memory Read Utilization    Idle (0)    Idle (0)    Idle (0)
          1                  sysmem_write_utilization                                       System Memory Write Utilization     Low (1)     Low (1)     Low (1)
          1               pcie_total_data_transmitted                                           PCIe Total Data Transmitted        1024        1024        1024
          1                  pcie_total_data_received                                              PCIe Total Data Received           0           0           0
          1                inst_executed_global_loads                              Warp level instructions for global loads    33554432    33554432    33554432
          1                 inst_executed_local_loads                               Warp level instructions for local loads           0           0           0
          1                inst_executed_shared_loads                              Warp level instructions for shared loads           0           0           0
          1               inst_executed_surface_loads                             Warp level instructions for surface loads           0           0           0
          1               inst_executed_global_stores                             Warp level instructions for global stores    33554432    33554432    33554432
          1                inst_executed_local_stores                              Warp level instructions for local stores           0           0           0
          1               inst_executed_shared_stores                             Warp level instructions for shared stores           0           0           0
          1              inst_executed_surface_stores                            Warp level instructions for surface stores           0           0           0
          1              inst_executed_global_atomics                  Warp level instructions for global atom and atom cas           0           0           0
          1           inst_executed_global_reductions                         Warp level instructions for global reductions           0           0           0
          1             inst_executed_surface_atomics                 Warp level instructions for surface atom and atom cas           0           0           0
          1          inst_executed_surface_reductions                        Warp level instructions for surface reductions           0           0           0
          1              inst_executed_shared_atomics                  Warp level shared instructions for atom and atom CAS           0           0           0
          1                     inst_executed_tex_ops                                   Warp level instructions for texture           0           0           0
          1                      l2_global_load_bytes       Bytes read from L2 for misses in Unified Cache for global loads  4294967296  4294967296  4294967296
          1                       l2_local_load_bytes        Bytes read from L2 for misses in Unified Cache for local loads           0           0           0
          1                     l2_surface_load_bytes      Bytes read from L2 for misses in Unified Cache for surface loads           0           0           0
          1               l2_local_global_store_bytes   Bytes written to L2 from Unified Cache for local and global stores.  4294967296  4294967296  4294967296
          1                 l2_global_reduction_bytes          Bytes written to L2 from Unified cache for global reductions           0           0           0
          1              l2_global_atomic_store_bytes             Bytes written to L2 from Unified cache for global atomics           0           0           0
          1                    l2_surface_store_bytes            Bytes written to L2 from Unified Cache for surface stores.           0           0           0
          1                l2_surface_reduction_bytes         Bytes written to L2 from Unified Cache for surface reductions           0           0           0
          1             l2_surface_atomic_store_bytes    Bytes transferred between Unified Cache and L2 for surface atomics           0           0           0
          1                      global_load_requests              Total number of global load requests from Multiprocessor   134217728   134217728   134217728
          1                       local_load_requests               Total number of local load requests from Multiprocessor           0           0           0
          1                     surface_load_requests             Total number of surface load requests from Multiprocessor           0           0           0
          1                     global_store_requests             Total number of global store requests from Multiprocessor   134217728   134217728   134217728
          1                      local_store_requests              Total number of local store requests from Multiprocessor           0           0           0
          1                    surface_store_requests            Total number of surface store requests from Multiprocessor           0           0           0
          1                    global_atomic_requests            Total number of global atomic requests from Multiprocessor           0           0           0
          1                 global_reduction_requests         Total number of global reduction requests from Multiprocessor           0           0           0
          1                   surface_atomic_requests           Total number of surface atomic requests from Multiprocessor           0           0           0
          1                surface_reduction_requests        Total number of surface reduction requests from Multiprocessor           0           0           0
          1                         sysmem_read_bytes                                              System Memory Read Bytes           0           0           0
          1                        sysmem_write_bytes                                             System Memory Write Bytes         160         160         160
          1                           l2_tex_hit_rate                                                     L2 Cache Hit Rate       0.00%       0.00%       0.00%
          1                     texture_load_requests             Total number of texture Load requests from Multiprocessor           0           0           0
          1                     unique_warps_launched                                              Number of warps launched       32768       32768       32768
          1                             sm_efficiency                                               Multiprocessor Activity      99.63%      99.63%      99.63%
          1                        achieved_occupancy                                                    Achieved Occupancy    0.986477    0.986477    0.986477
          1                                       ipc                                                          Executed IPC    0.344513    0.344513    0.344513
          1                                issued_ipc                                                            Issued IPC    0.344574    0.344574    0.344574
          1                    issue_slot_utilization                                                Issue Slot Utilization       8.61%       8.61%       8.61%
          1                  eligible_warps_per_cycle                                       Eligible Warps Per Active Cycle    0.592326    0.592326    0.592326
          1                           tex_utilization                                             Unified Cache Utilization     Low (1)     Low (1)     Low (1)
          1                            l2_utilization                                                  L2 Cache Utilization     Low (2)     Low (2)     Low (2)
          1                        shared_utilization                                             Shared Memory Utilization    Idle (0)    Idle (0)    Idle (0)
          1                       ldst_fu_utilization                                  Load/Store Function Unit Utilization     Low (1)     Low (1)     Low (1)
          1                         cf_fu_utilization                                Control-Flow Function Unit Utilization     Low (1)     Low (1)     Low (1)
          1                    special_fu_utilization                                     Special Function Unit Utilization    Idle (0)    Idle (0)    Idle (0)
          1                        tex_fu_utilization                                     Texture Function Unit Utilization     Low (1)     Low (1)     Low (1)
          1           single_precision_fu_utilization                            Single-Precision Function Unit Utilization     Low (1)     Low (1)     Low (1)
          1           double_precision_fu_utilization                            Double-Precision Function Unit Utilization    Idle (0)    Idle (0)    Idle (0)
          1                        flop_hp_efficiency                                            FLOP Efficiency(Peak Half)       0.00%       0.00%       0.00%
          1                        flop_sp_efficiency                                          FLOP Efficiency(Peak Single)       0.00%       0.00%       0.00%
          1                        flop_dp_efficiency                                          FLOP Efficiency(Peak Double)       0.00%       0.00%       0.00%
          1                    dram_read_transactions                                       Device Memory Read Transactions   134218560   134218560   134218560
          1                   dram_write_transactions                                      Device Memory Write Transactions   134176900   134176900   134176900
          1                      dram_read_throughput                                         Device Memory Read Throughput  150.32GB/s  150.32GB/s  150.32GB/s
          1                     dram_write_throughput                                        Device Memory Write Throughput  150.27GB/s  150.27GB/s  150.27GB/s
          1                          dram_utilization                                             Device Memory Utilization    High (7)    High (7)    High (7)
          1             half_precision_fu_utilization                              Half-Precision Function Unit Utilization    Idle (0)    Idle (0)    Idle (0)
          1                          ecc_transactions                                                      ECC Transactions           0           0           0
          1                            ecc_throughput                                                        ECC Throughput  0.00000B/s  0.00000B/s  0.00000B/s
          1                           dram_read_bytes                                Total bytes read from DRAM to L2 cache  4294993920  4294993920  4294993920
          1                          dram_write_bytes                             Total bytes written from L2 cache to DRAM  4293660800  4293660800  4293660800
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Fermi and Kepler GPUs, when a global transaction was issued, it was always for 128 bytes, and the L1 cacheline size (if enabled) was 128 bytes.  With Maxwell and Pascal, these characteristics changed.  In particular, a read of a portion of an L1 cacheline does not necessarily trigger a full 128-byte width transaction.  This is fairly easily discoverable/provable with microbenchmarking.

Effectively, the size of a global load transaction changed, subject to a certain quantum of granularity.  Based on this change of transaction size, it's possible that multiple transactions could be required, where previously only 1 was required.  As far as I know, none of this is clearly published or detailed, and I won't be able to do that here.  However I think we can address a number of your questions without giving a precise description of how global load transactions are calculated.

> `gld_transactions` = 536870914, which means that every global load transaction should on average be 4GB/536870914 = 8 bytes. This is consistent with `gld_transactions_per_request` = 16.000000: Each warp reads 128 bytes (1 request) and if every transaction is 8 bytes, then we need 128 / 8 = 16 transactions per request. Why is this value so low? I would expect perfect coalescing, so something along the lines of 4 (or even 1) transactions/request.

This mindset (1 transaction per request for fully coalesced loads of a 32-bit quantity per thread) would have been correct in the Fermi/Kepler timeframe.  It is no longer correct for Maxwell and Pascal GPUs.  As you've already calculated, the transaction size appears to be smaller than 128 bytes, and therefore the number of transactions per request is higher than 1.  But this doesn't indicate an efficiency problem per se (as it would have in Fermi/Kepler timeframe).  So let's just acknowledge that the transaction size can be smaller and therefore transactions per request can be higher, even though the underlying traffic is essentially 100% efficient.

> gst_transactions = 134217728 and gst_transactions_per_request = 4.000000, so storing memory is more efficient?

No, that's not what this means.  It simply means that the subdivision quanta can be different for loads (load transactions) and stores (store transactions).  These happen to be 32-byte transactions.  In either case, loads or stores, the transactions are and should be fully efficient in this case.  The requested traffic is consistent with the actual traffic, and other profiler metrics confirm this.  If the actual traffic were much higher than the requested traffic, that would be a good indication of inefficient loads or stores:

```
  1                  gld_requested_throughput                                      Requested Global Load Throughput  150.32GB/s  150.32GB/s  150.32GB/s
  1                  gst_requested_throughput                                     Requested Global Store Throughput  150.32GB/s  150.32GB/s  150.32GB/s
  1                            gld_throughput                                                Global Load Throughput  150.32GB/s  150.32GB/s  150.32GB/s
  1                            gst_throughput                                               Global Store Throughput  150.32GB/s  150.32GB/s  150.32GB/s
```

> Requested and achieved global load/store throughput (gld_requested_throughput, gst_requested_throughput, gld_throughput, gst_throughput) is 150.32GB/s each. I would expect a lower throughput for loads than for stores since we have more transactions per request.

Again, you'll have to adjust your way of thinking to account for variable transaction sizes.  Throughput is driven by the needs and efficiency associated with fulfilling those needs.  Both loads and stores are fully efficient for your code design, so there is no reason to think there is or should be an imbalance in efficiency.

> gld_transactions = 536870914 but l2_read_transactions = 134218800. Global memory is always accessed through the L1/L2 caches. Why is the number of L2 read transactions so much lower? It can't all be cached in the L1. (global_hit_rate = 0%)

This is simply due to the different size of the transactions.  You've already calculated that the apparent global load transaction size is 8 bytes, and I've already indicated that the L2 transaction size is 32 bytes, so it makes sense that there would be a 4:1 ratio between the total number of transactions, since they reflect the same movement of the same data, viewed through 2 different lenses.  Note that there has always been a disparity in the size of global transactions vs. the size of L2 transactions, or transactions to DRAM.  Its simply that the ratios of these may vary by GPU architecture, and possibly other factors, such as load patterns.

Some notes:

- I won't be able to answer questions such as "why is it this way?", or "why did Pascal change from Fermi/Kepler?" or "given this particular code, what would you predict as the needed global load transactions on this particular GPU?", or "generally, for this particular GPU, how would I calculate or predict transaction size?"
- As an aside, there are new profiling tools (Nsight Compute and Nsight Systems) being advanced by NVIDIA for GPU work.  Many of the efficiency and transactions per request metrics which are available in `nvprof` [are gone](https://docs.nvidia.com/nsight-compute/NsightComputeCli/index.html#nvprof-metric-comparison) under the new toolchain.  So these mindsets will have to be broken anyway, because these methods of ascertaining efficiency won't be available moving forward, based on the current metric set.
- Note that the use of compile switches such as `-Xptxas -dlcm=ca` may affect (L1) caching behavior.  I don't expect caches to have much performance or efficiency impact on this particular copy code, however.
- This possible reduction in transaction size is generally a good thing.  It results in no loss of efficiency for traffic patterns such as presented in this code, and for certain other codes it allows (less-than-128byte) requests to be satisfied with less wasted bandwidth.
- Although not specifically Pascal, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29241623/1695960) is a better defined example of the possible variability in these measurements for Maxwell.  Pascal will have similar variability.  Also, some small hint of this change (especially for Pascal) was given in the [Pascal Tuning Guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/pascal-tuning-guide/index.html#l1-cache). It by no means offers a complete description or explains all of your observations, but it does hint at the general idea that the global transactions are no longer fixed to a 128-byte size.

Comment: Thank you, this makes more sense to me now. The CUDA C Programming Guide describes the [rules for memory coalescing](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#global-memory-3-0), but for the much older CC 3.x. (Newer CC paragraphs partly forward to CC 3.x.) The architecture/hardware must have changed a lot since then. But it seems like, while some hardware details (#transcations etc.) may have changed, most CUDA programmers can just ignore this and keep following the same set of rules for getting good memory throughput.

Comment: Some small hint of this change (especially for Pascal) was given in the [Pascal Tuning Guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/pascal-tuning-guide/index.html#l1-cache).  It by no means offers a complete description or explains all of your observations, but it does hint at the general idea that the global transactions are no longer fixed to a 128-byte size.

Comment: [This thread](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1006066/cuda-programming-and-performance/pascal-l1-cache/) may also be of interest.

Comment: @Robert Crovella: While implementing matrix transpose, I found that though the text book advised optimizations using Global memory access coalescing, shared memory, bank conflict avoidance etc. give intuitive profiling results (in terms of #transactions as above) for _Tesla K40_ or _K80_ gpus, but in case of Maxwell, Pascal or Turing I did not get expected reduction in `gld transactions`. My simple question is: does it mean this traditionally advised practices for cuda prog. are no longer valid in newer GPU architectures? I think they don't apply, just want to confirm if it is the case.

Comment: I am a beginner in cuda programming and all the books/materials I find, provide examples of coalescing and all optimizations which I think have got obsolete. Is there any similar reference for best practices for cuda programming in newer architectures?

Comment: no they are not obsolete. [this article](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/analysis-driven-optimization-analyzing-and-improving-performance-with-nvidia-nsight-compute-part-2) for example, shows the benefits of restructuring code to take advantage of global load coalescing in tesla V100.  The coalescing changes are developed in the section entitled "Restructuring", with the analysis prior to that.